# Python Telegram Prevent Ctrl+C propagating to telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, telegram

Using Python 3.11 on Windows 11

My program is using asyncio. The main coroutine initalizes everything and then just waits for ctrl+c to cleanup resources before terminating.

The main entry point in my program is:

```
# unit testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(HTTP_URL))
    s = Supervisor(w3)
    asyncio.run(s.main())
```

Supervisor.main is defined as:

```
    # launch telegram and enter infinite loop to await track commands
    async def main(self):
        self.telegram = Telegram_Bot(self)
        await self.telegram.start()
        try:
            while True:
                await asyncio.sleep(3600)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(f'caught {type(e)}')
            print('cleaing up resources...')
            for addr in self.trackers:
                self.kill_tracker(addr)
            await self.telegram.stop()
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            print('exiting program')
```

And Telegram_Bot.start is defined:
(I had to use the lower level API instead of just application.run_polling() because I already have an asyncio event loop running)

```
    async def start(self):
        print('starting telegram bot...')
        await self.application.initialize()
        await self.application.updater.start_polling()
        await self.application.start()
        self.__tracking_task = asyncio.create_task(self.__handle_tracking())
        print('telegram bot initialized')
```

And Telegram_Bot.end is defined:

```
    async def stop(self):
        await self.application.updater.stop()
        await self.application.stop()
        await self.application.shutdown()
        print('telegram bot stopped')
```

I want to be able to gracefully exit the program via Ctrl+C. However, I often get this message:

```
2024-01-18 15:23:54,963 - telegram.ext.Application - WARNING - Fetching updates got a asyncio.CancelledError. Ignoring as this task may onlybe closed via `Application.stop`.
```

This then does something that blocks the event loop from ever finishing so the awaitable telegram.stop() never finishes

I have tried using various except catches all the way down to the BaseException and still somehow it gets propagated to the telegram coroutine. I am expecting to be able to catch the exception and not have the telegram.ext.Application receive an asyncio.CancelledError.

What is especially weird is sometimes the code works as intended and I get no such warning message. I am unable to readily reproduce instances where it gracefully exits but it has happened a few times during my testing:

```
starting telegram bot...
2024-01-18 15:43:52,597 - httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot.../getMe "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2024-01-18 15:43:52,760 - httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot.../deleteWebhook "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2024-01-18 15:43:52,760 - telegram.ext.Application - INFO - Application started
telegram bot initialized
caught <class 'asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError'>
cleaing up resources...
2024-01-18 15:43:57,683 - httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.telegram.org/bot.../getUpdates "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2024-01-18 15:43:57,683 - telegram.ext.Application - INFO - Application is stopping. This might take a moment.
2024-01-18 15:43:57,683 - telegram.ext.Application - INFO - Application.stop() complete
telegram bot stopped
exiting program
```

Comment: Have you tried capturing and printing the entire traceback, instead of suppressing that information?  You could insert these 2 lines in your except block: `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()`.  If your code is not canceling updates, perhaps you can figure out where that is coming from.